# All produced kafka messages are sending always to partition 0 even the key hash value is 1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kafka topic with 2 partitions. and I have created a message handler with 2 different keys.

```
   @Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pushDataRequestChannel")
public MessageHandler pushDataRequestHandler(final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
    handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression(topicProperties.getProducerKey()));
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel processDataRequestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processDataRequestChannel")
public MessageHandler processDataRequestHandler(final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
    handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression(topicProperties.getProducerKeyOne()));
    return handler;
}
```

1. group_id
2. partition_1_key

so. I'm going to send messages to partition 0, only for odd numbers. for event numbers it should go to partition 1.

Here is my logic

```
for(int i=0; i < 6 ; i++)
        {
            Predicate<Integer> isEven = n -> n % 2 == 0;

            // Check if the number is even or odd and display the result
            if (isEven.test(i)) {
                System.out.println(i + " is an even number.");
                MessageNeedToSend message = new MessageNeedToSend();
                ----
                ---
                ---
                pushDataRequestChannel.send(MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message))
                        .copyHeaders(headers)
                        .build());
            } else {
                MessageNeedToSend message = new MessageNeedToSend();
                ----
                ---
                ---
                processDataRequestChannel.send(MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message))
                        .copyHeaders(headers)
                        .build());
                System.out.println(i + " is an odd number.");
            }
        }
```

But it's always going to partition 0.

partition_1_key - 706172746974696F6E5F315F6B6579 (byte array) -- 1550936367 (murmur hash 2)- 1550936367 % 2 = 1 - ( as per my understanding it should go partition 1)

group_id - 67726F75705F6964 (byte array) -- 2186850892 (murmur hash 2)- 2186850892 % 2 = 0 - ( as per my understanding it should go partition 0)

but it always going to  partition 0;

can you tell me what might be the reason

Answer (score 1):

The partitioner logic has been changed. When a batch is computed, all records stick to the same partition, rather than distribute amongst all based on each key

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-794%3A+Strictly+Uniform+Sticky+Partitioner

Answer (score 0):

[ProducerRecord](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html) allows you to specify the partition number instead of having two handlers.
Using spring boot [KafkaProducerMessageHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/kafka/outbound/KafkaProducerMessageHandler.html#setPartitionIdExpression(org.springframework.expression.Expression))  , you can send the message to topic by specifying the `partition id` using `setPartitionIdExpression` instead of using key in calculation of the partition id.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Kenneth Chirchir.

But I want to achieve this by using a key. I don't want to mention partition id. In the future, if partitions are increased we need to do a code change. in your approach

Comment: What does `topicProperties.getProducerKey()` and `topicProperties.getProducerOneKey()` return? Perhaps these is the key being set

Comment: It will return group_id and partition_1_key. yes those are the keys - @Kenneth Chirchir